# Any good places to learn about JS de-obfuscation?

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

I am trying to make a bot on a specific website, so I have to reverse a lot of JS scripts. The reversing it self is not that hard but the de-obfuscation is. Lots of the scripts are obfuscated with things like JScrambler. I see people able to de-obfuscate JScrambler but for me it is very difficult. So I wanted to know if there was any place I could learn about JS de-obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some cool materials that can assist in your analysis and learning about analysis techniques for obfuscated Javascript, notice that the best way is still to debug the obfuscated code through your own browser debugger (as different from virtualized codes, the logic does not change).

- [Akamai JS Obfuscation](https://blogs.akamai.com/sitr/2020/10/catch-me-if-you-can---javascript-obfuscation.html)
- [JS Reverse from InfoSec](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/reverse-engineering-javascript-obfuscated-dropper/)
- [Livestream Reversing and Deobfuscate JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxgEwi6LfLc)

Here are some tools that help your life as well:

- [De4Js](http://lelinhtinh.github.io/de4js)
- [javascript-deobfuscator](https://github.com/LostMyCode/javascript-deobfuscator)
- [jscrambler-reverse-engineering](https://github.com/oncecreated/jscrambler-reverse-engineering)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add to your list

[javascript deobfuscator](https://seosniffer.com/javascript-deobfuscator)
[javascript obfuscator](https://seosniffer.com/javascript-obfuscator)

I hope i don't get banned for sharing these links my intention is only to help

Comment: Can you describe the contents and significance of these links?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).